# access SQL error with order by and group by

Tags: group-by, sql-order-by

I am working on a homework exercise and I am ussing MS access 2013 and I am writing  and sql that produces a query tha is supposed to Show the LastName and FirstName of all customers who have had an order with an Item named 'Dress Shirt'. Use a subquery. Present the results sorted by LastName, in ascending order and then FirstName in descending order. This is the code I wrote following what I have learned from the book

SELECT LastName, FirstName

FROM CUSTOMER, INVOICE_ITEM

WHERE Item In 
   (SELECT Item
   FROM INVOICE_ITEM
   WHERE Item="Dress Shirt") 
GROUP BY LastName
 ORDER BY FirstName DESC;

I get an error that my query does not include a specified expression 'FirstName' as part of an agregate funtion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by with all the fields in select statement unless you count, sum, etc

Try:

SELECT LastName, FirstName

FROM CUSTOMER, INVOICE_ITEM

WHERE Item In (SELECT Item FROM INVOICE_ITEM WHERE Item="Dress Shirt") GROUP BY LastName, FirstName ORDER BY FirstName DESC;